# JavaScript issue in Android 4.1.2

Tags: javascript, android, ios

I have a piece of javaScript code as :

```
var val = parseInt("08");
alert("Val : " + val);
```

It displays val as 0.

Where as the same piece of code in iOS displays 8.

Can someone shed more light on this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried adding the radix? var val = parseInt("08",10);

Comment: Not a bug, it is working perfectly. Learn about parseInt(). The IOS would be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because you are using parseInt without defining which radix to use. Now it thinks you are using 8 as the radix.

Try this:

```
var val = parseInt('08', 10);
```